What is this permission problem with adb?
I would like to transfer files between a phone (Harmony 2.0.0) and a Linux laptop with USB connection between them.
I try to use adb by following https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/hde7f4/enable_linux_mounting_of_android_usb_device_for/fvl8gyp/, but why do I have the permission problem?
$ adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
A7Q0218123000244    no permissions; see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]



$ adb shell
adb: insufficient permissions for device
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information

I can't find anything useful in the link http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Did you try visiting those links in the output?

"I can't find anything useful in the link" Really? From the link: "Each user that wants to use ADB needs to be in the plugdev group." Could be something that's relevant for permissions, no?

@muru, If so, could you combine your finding with Artem's answer which doesn't mention what you found?

The link also mentions udev, you should check whether it matches what Artem's answer says, first.

You either have to

run adb under root/sudo
or create a udev rule for your Android device, e.g. something like:

/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="abcd", MODE="0660", GROUP="user"

Or you can remove , GROUP="user" from above and change mode to 0666.
You can get the vendor ID by using the lsusb command. After ID you'll see VENDOR:DEVICE.

Thanks. (1) For the part in ATTR{idVendor}=="...",  is it 12d1 according the output of lsusb in my https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/779420/how-shall-i-find-the-device-of-a-phones-storage-so-that-i-can-mount-it-in-linux? (2) If I have more than one phones (Honor 10 and Moto G Pure), and I may want to connect either to the Linux laptop, what shall the content of  /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules be like?

You may have multiple SUBSYSTEM ... strings in this file or create multiple files with different idVendor's. Or you can have a single line and file and use | for different idVendors, e.g.  ATTR{idVendor}=="abcd|cdef|1234" - though I've not tested it. Personally I've created multiple files and named them according to the vendor. You can check /usr/lib/udev/rules.d to see how they are organized.

sudo adb devices and sudo adb shell both don't solve the problem

First run this sudo killall adb, then try the other commands.

Thanks. It works.

Is  sudo adb kill-server effectively the same?

Why did I ask to sudo? Because I didn't know under what account you ran it and sudo will kill the process of any user. If your user is always e.g. tim, you can adb kill-server without using sudo. I just wanted a quick fix for you.
